# Mercurial: how to prevent commit/push if untracked files exists in working copy?

Tags: git, mercurial

What i like about `git` is manual `add` functionality. Since you need to add all changes, you never miss new files. In `mercurial` it's often a case where i do some changes, issue `hg diff`, review them, commit - and after some time i suddenly realize that i created a new file or two but forgot to `hg add` it.

Is it any way to prevent `mercurial` from commiting (or pushing) if i have untracked files in my working copy?

Comment: It's definitely possible to miss new files in git, I've done it. :-)  I just use `git status` and `hg status` heavily to avoid this, I don't have any automated method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are pre commit and change group hooks that you can implement to automatically reject commit/push when there are untracked, unignored, files present - and a lot more stuff.